# Spherical Distance-From-Center Gradient

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, workflow, shaders

Using this simple node setup, i'm able to get a pretty good gradient for this kind of mesh :
[image]

[image]

Could it be possible to get the same kind of gradient with a sphere like this one ?
[image]

I mean, the further the face get from the center of the sphere, the whiter it will get, and vice-versa.
Hope someone here can help me !

PS : I'm french, so my english may not be perfect ^^

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/how-to-make-a-good-glow-effect-around-a-sun/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether it's the best approach but here's how I would wing it:

[image: gradient node setup]

Giving that result:

[image: gradient result]

The gradient texture has its origin at the object origin and creates a virtual sphere that gets brighter and brighter which creates darker valleys and brighter mountains. Once upon a time it was called a blend texture.

Comment: Why the Diffuse/Emission mix? Could you not just feed the Color from the ramp straight into the Emission color?

Comment: @RichSedman Because I'm 85% dysnodic and I get cheap admission to museums with that disability. Although I'd like to make the lame excuse that mixing different shaders can be more flexible than the gradient which translates to: you're probably right. Just tested it. Move to strike 'probably'

Comment: CONVOLUDIRATION RULZ!!!

Comment: Either way, it works :-) I believe an emission with no color or zero strength is effectively a black diffuse.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:
[image]

This node setup won't take the distance of a point from the origin, but rather the curvature (pointiness) of the surface at a given point, however it might be good enough for your purposes.