# Cannot see original object after using a blur node in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to make a blur (or a kind of haze) around a sphere using a blur node in the compositor. Currently, there is a blur but the object itself isn't visible. Is there a way to make the object visible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you upload your file or share a screenshot of your compositing nodes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/how-to-make-a-good-glow-effect-around-a-sun/