# How to create a glowing object in a light background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am creating an atom model and want a glowing nucleus in cycles render. Something like this.

[image: Desired Output]

My nucleus is a single sphere.
I need it to glow but I need a light background. Is it possible?

This is what I have.
[image: My Model]

Comment: this might be usefull https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a good glow effect around a sun?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/how-to-make-a-good-glow-effect-around-a-sun)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have something dark in your image to make the glow work. It needs contrast or it will look washed out. You have made your rings black and you could try to make the nucleus light up those. That could make the nucleus appear to emit light.

Maybe something like this?

[image]

Here is the material node setup for the glowy thing in the middle.
It can be applied to any object larger than the falloff radius.
It controls how mush light that should be emitted by the volume by creating a gradient from the objects center and out.

[image]

Comment: This looks really good. Can you attach the node layout/material settings you used. I am really just starting on materials in blender.

Answer (score 1):

Within the compositor you can add a glare node (fog glow) to your scene/renderlayer, that will do the trick.