# Making a spherical gradient that becomes transparent towards the outside

Tags: materials

I want to know if there's a way to create the following material: A spherical gradient that is red in the center and gets transparent farther away from the center.
I want to apply such a material to a plane object.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65706/how-to-make-a-good-glow-effect-around-a-sun/65711#65711 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/transparency-masking-see-through-an-outer-sphere-and-see-inner-sphere-in-true/70619#70619

Answer (score 3):

As Rob suggests you can use a *Gradient* node in *Quadratic Sphere* mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make changes to get it how you want.  I'm not sure what changes exactly, sorry, but this might work for you.  GL

[image]

Comment: Someone will probably have a better/simpler solution.  I just had this image handy, lol.  You can Google search for **"gradient material in blender"** and switch the search type to **Images**, you'll find something that works : )

Comment: Yeah thanks, this was almost what I wanted actually. Except that instead of the transparency being in the inner part of the circle I want it to be on the outer part. In short exactly the inverse of the above transparency effect. I tried to google it, unfortunately I didn't get any images corresponding to what I wanted. Do you know how to achieve the inverse of the above?

Comment: Also look at the "Gradient Shader" set to "Quadratic Sphere"

Comment: Flip the transparent shader and the other shaders : )  Oh and it works in Cycles, as is, but for Eevee, you need to set the material blend mode to Alpha.  GL

Comment: As rob said, you can **mix a shader with a transparent shader** and use the **Gradient Texture node as the mix factor**.  Just remember for **Eevee** to change the material settings so it uses the **alpha**.  It seems to work well : )